# CSS HTML Generate PDF file from image with text under it

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, css-to-pdf

I want to **generate a PDF** file using the [xepOnline.jqPlugin.js](https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf) plugin.

I have an image (on the "background") and an HTML text under the image.
I am capable to generate the PDF file but there are two different elements: the image and, after the image (and not under the image), comes the text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
<script src="xepOnline.jqPlugin.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page-show">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/Card.png" >
        <h3>TEXT</h3>
    </div>

    <button id="PrintButton" onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('page-show',{render:'download'});"/>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS for the relevant elements is the following:

```
#page-show{
    /* The main container div */
    width:355px;
    margin:90px auto 0;
}

div.img {
    height: 165px;
    text-align: center;
}   

div.img img {
    display: inline;
}

.image { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
    text-align: center;
}

h3 { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 164px; 
    width: 100%; 
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**Is it possible to generate a PDF file of the image with the text under it?** 
(with the same format as it appears in the HTML page)

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean because you do not here post a fiddle or something pointing to the page so we can see what card.png is and what the expected output is.

Comment: You are right @Kevin Brown. Please find the example at http://jsfiddle.net/lmmanica/0d6wfub9/4/

Comment: OK, now I understand your question. You want to "overlay" text onto the image in question. CSS2PDF was not designed for that as it does not support position:absolute and top/left attributes. If this is somethine you would like to support we might consider it. Our standard client-side (non-web-browser) tools do all of that as we don;t really expect people to use absolutely positioned content in bootstrap/flowing web content. Shout out on Github project for the Javascript and maybe one of the developer's will take it on.

Comment: I have been working on adding relative/absolute positioning ... you may wish to examine this page in our beta site ... http://beta.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Development.AbsolutePosition

Comment: That's pretty close to what I need. I will look for any new developments and thank you for your suggestions and effort on this.

Comment: Great. I pushed that sample to the main site now. http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.AbsolutePosition

Comment: I also need to print the table under the svg and how I will print this with table with SVG in the PDF ???